# How to update multiple rows at once from a View (ASP.NET - Core)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm trying to create an view in which multiple values can be edited at once. The view consists of multiple rows from a List in which I want to check a checkbox to change the value of the boolean `EnableAlertsUpload` to `True` or `False`, as can be seen in the following picture:

[image]

When the Update button gets pressed the `IActionResult Edit` should be called which updates all the `EnableAlertsUpload` booleans in the database. The database is made using the Code First approach with Entity Framework Core.

When i press the Update button right now a new record will be created and all values are set to `NULL`. So it seems there is an issue with my `SaveDevice` method in the Repository

**AlertsController**

```
    public ViewResult Devices()
        => View(new DevicesViewModel
        {
            Devices = repo.getDevices()
        });

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(Devices devices)
    {
        repo.SaveDevice(devices);

        return RedirectToAction();
    }
```

**Repository**

```
    public void SaveDevice(Devices devices)
    {
        if (devices.objid == 0)
        {
            db.Devices.Add(devices);
        }
        else
        {
            Devices dbEntry = db.Devices
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.objid == devices.objid);
            if (dbEntry != null)
            {
                dbEntry.objid = devices.objid;
                dbEntry.device = devices.device;
                dbEntry.group = devices.group;
                dbEntry.host = devices.host;
                dbEntry.EnableAlertsUpload = devices.EnableAlertsUpload;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Devices**

```
public partial class Devices
{
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int objid { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public bool EnableAlertsUpload { get; set; }
}
```

**DevicesViewModel**

```
public class DevicesViewModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Devices> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

**Devices View**

```
@model Models.ViewModels.DevicesViewModel  
  
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Device</th>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Enabled Alerts Update</th>
        </tr>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Devices.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Devices[i].objid" />
                    @Model.Devices[i].objid
                </td>
                <td>@Model.Devices[i].device</td>
                <td>@Model.Devices[i].group</td>
                <td>@Model.Devices[i].host</td>
                <td><input asp-for="Devices[i].EnableAlertsUpload"/></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <button input type="submit" value="Edit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your POST edit method is only expecting a single `Devices` object, not a collection of them.  Try `public IActionResult Edit(Devices[] devices)`.  Your repository method will also need to be changed to expect a list of devices.  You will then need to foreach loop through them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, according to the code snippets (in the controller method), it seems that your application is an Asp.Net Core MVC application, right? If that is the case, I think the DevicesViewModel model is no need to inherit the PageModel (Generally, the PageModel is used in the RazorPage). Because it seems that if we using it in Asp.net Core MVC application, it will [show An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FETso.png).

So, for the Asp.net Core MVC application, I suggest you could modify your code as below (remove the PageModel):

```
public class DevicesViewModel 
{       
    public List<Devices> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

> When i press the Update button right now a new record will be created
> and all values are set to NULL. So it seems there is an issue with my
> SaveDevice method in the Repository

Then, for above issue, we can see in the Devices View, the view model is `DevicesViewModel` , so, after click the `Update` button it will submit this model, instead of `Devices` model. And, in the Devices view, since you directly display the data into the `<td>` tag, after submit the form, these property values will be `null`, you could set a break point in the Edit method to verify it.

To solve above issue, in the Devices View, you could use hidden field control to display the property values and in the Edit action method you could use the `DevicesViewModel`.

You could refer the following code:

Model code:

```
public class Devices
{
    [Key()]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int objid { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string device { get; set; }
    public string host { get; set; }
    public bool EnableAlertsUpload { get; set; }
}
public class DevicesViewModel 
{       
    public List<Devices> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

Code in the Devices View:

```
    @model MVCDemo.Models.DevicesViewModel 
    <form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Device</th>
                <th>Group</th>
                <th>Host</th>
                <th>Enabled Alerts Update</th>
            </tr>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Devices.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Devices[i].objid" />
                        @Model.Devices[i].objid
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Devices[i].device" />
                        @Model.Devices[i].device
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Devices[i].group" />
                        @Model.Devices[i].group
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Devices[i].host" />
                        @Model.Devices[i].host
                    </td>
                    <td><input asp-for="Devices[i].EnableAlertsUpload" /></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <button input type="submit" value="Edit">Update</button>
    </form>
```

Code in the Edit action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(DevicesViewModel device)
    {
        if(device != null && device.Devices.Count>0)
        {
            //Since there might have multiple devices, use a foreach statement to loop though the devices and call the SaveDevice method to update data.
            foreach (var item in device.Devices)
            {
                repo.SaveDevice(item);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

[image]

Finally, if you want to edit the string type property value, in the Devices View, you could use the following code to display the value.

```
    <input asp-for="@Model.Devices[i].device" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the amazing answer and clear explanation, it's exactly what I was looking for, everything works like intended :). I was a bit confused by the usage of a ViewModel and it seems I got the Devices Object and the ViewModel a bit mixed up. I'll take some time to study this subject to fully understand the process. Thanks again for taking the time to answer my question in such an clear way!

Comment: I'm wondering how you were able to recreate the project so fast. Is there any template out there with basic CRUD functionality and also Identity Framework (since I also see a Register button). If so, could you please let me know where to find it?

Comment: Hi @Bram, For the basic CRUD function, I'm also using EF core, after generating the database and configure the dbcontext (Repository), we could directly achieve the CRUD function via the dbcontext, you could refer the [following tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0). For the Identity, you could use the Scaffold Identity in your application, check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

Input is not directly update binding your list but `checkboxfor` does. Because `checkboxfor` will add a checkbox type hidden field automatically.

```
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Devices[i].EnableAlertsUpload)</td>
```

Other wise you could update your razor view

```
<td><input asp-for="Devices[i].EnableAlertsUpload"/>
 <input type="hidden" asp-for="Devices[i].EnableAlertsUpload" />
</td>
```