# ASP.NET Core MVC - Data does not pass from the view to the controller in a post request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried following this similar question: [How to update multiple rows at once from a View (ASP.NET - Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65282584/how-to-update-multiple-rows-at-once-from-a-view-asp-net-core)
Everything is almost structurally similar but the data from the view still could not go to the controller.

Here is the view model:

```
public class ManageUsersViewModel
{
       public Guid? ProjectId;
       public List<ProjectUserRowModel> ProjectUserRows;
       public List<ProjectRole> ProjectRoles;
}
```

```
public class ProjectUserRowModel
{
       public Guid Guid { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
       public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the view (Just the form/table for brevity):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="ManageUsersSave" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProjectId"/>
            <table>
                @for (var i=0; i < Model.ProjectUserRows.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProjectUserRows[i].Guid" />
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProjectUserRows[i].Name" />
                            @Model.ProjectUserRows[i].Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.ProjectUserRows[i].Email" />
                            @Model.ProjectUserRows[i].Email
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select asp-for="@Model.ProjectUserRows[i].RoleId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.ProjectRoles, "ProjectRoleId", "Name", @Model.ProjectUserRows[i].RoleId))">
                                <option value="">-- Project Role</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a asp-action="DeleteProjectUser" asp-route-id="@Model.ProjectUserRows[i].Guid" class="text-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the declaration of the method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ManageUsersSave([Bind("ProjectId,ProjectUserRows,ProjectRoles")]ManageUsersViewModel manageUsersViewModel)
```

I could not find any errors at all except that the values when processing the object, the values are null.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the `Bind` attribute. Regardless: why the `Bind`? The only purpose of `Bind` is that it will let you specify the exact properties a model should include or exclude in binding. But in your case you need all 3 properties. Did you try `FromForm` (`[FromForm] ManageUsersViewModel manageUsersViewModel` ) ?

Comment: To be honest, I'm just trying out every attribute I could use. Bind worked for every other form in the program except for this one which involves bulk updates. Which might be because Bind is usually for non-multi-dimensional values but I was hoping just maybe it might work. Haha it didn't. I just tried [FromForm] and the data still didn't pass through, unfortunately.

Comment: Now that I notice, you are using [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), not [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) (in short, you are missing the `{ get; set;}`'s. The model binder only works with properties.

Comment: Oh my god. I love you. I might have not used the prop shortcut there that's why I forgot about that. Thanks a lot. It worked now.

Comment: Imma post an answer, if you be kind to accept it. :D

Comment: Sure, absolutely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I notice you are using [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), not [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in the `ManageUsersViewModel` model.
The model binder only works for **properties**.

Also a note on the `[Bind]` attribute. I'm not very familiar with it, whether it  recognizes form data or not. If it doesn't work, use the [[FromForm]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Haven't tried [FromForm] attribute but it worked without any attribute. Thanks again!

Comment: I emphasized it because you can receive data from different sources (from header, from body, from query ...)  and it's easy for the eye to miss it. [Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sources)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you specify FromBody instead of Bind?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ManageUsersSave([FromBody]ManageUsersViewModel manageUsersViewModel)
```

Comment: This is formulated as a comment. If you don't know the answer, and aren't allowed to post comments, you just have to wait.

Comment: It showed Error 415 (Unsupported Media Type) and it didn't run any code inside the action method.

Comment: follow up: This actually works too if the properties have been correctly declared. Thank you for contributing still. :)

Comment: No problem :) Actually I didn't noticed that you had declared the ManageUsersViewModel as fields instead of properties, as the correct answer pointed out. Sometimes it's the tiny details that get us ahah.